# My website running in Oracle Cloud is down, how can I repair it?

Tags: ssh, server, oracle-cloud-infrastructure

I have a website that is running in Oracle Cloud, the website now is down and I tried to access using SSH in Putty but it cannot be accessed I only see the terminal screen.

What should I do?

[image]

Answer (score 0):

Could you please check if the instance is running or not. If the instance is running please check for the ingress/egress firewall rules at security list/NSG/OS firewall for connectivity to the instance. Make sure you are not connected to any VPN or any corporate network. Once you are able to connect to the instance check for the status of the service. It should be Active.

Could you please confirm, were you able to connect to the instance before? Since when you are facing this issue?

For your reference: [connecting to your instance](https://docs.oracle.com/en-us/iaas/Content/GSG/Tasks/testingconnection.htm).

Comment: Hello Anupam Sinha! I would like to thank you for your help. I solved this issue by rebooting the instance in Oracle Cloud, it's strange I couldn't find a logical reason for this but it works. I was able before to connect to the instance using SSH in Putty and it was working fine before this issue happened. Thanks again for providing the help!

Comment: I had this problem too and restarting it does help, but I couldn't even get a serial console connection to connect, it would also just hang. Curious how to troubleshoot it, as it may also happen to you again. Has happened to me twice in a few months.